# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndex:]2

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json

i am getting data from webservice which is locally published in my desktop machine. this is my json response.i am getting this data n the form of array name json array. in this array data is coming properly but when i am converting data into array it is throwin exception above.
below is my sample code for getting data.
}

```
-(void) retrievedata
{

    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.3:8080/GetEmployees.svc/json/employees"]];  // this is your request url

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];     // here parsing the array

    NSArray *firstArry=[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"GetAllEmployeesMethodResult"];// getting error in this line
}
```

below is my response:

```
{
    GetAllEmployeesMethodResult =     (
                {
            firstentry = 5;
            secondentry = "SANTE (PVT) LIMITED";
        },
                {
            firstentry = 8;
            secondentry = "ALLIANCE PHARMACEUTICALS (PVT) LTD";
        },
                {
            firstentry = 9;
            secondentry = "BARRETT HODGSON PAKISTAN (PVT) LTD.";
        },
                {
            firstentry = 7;
            secondentry = "GETZ PHARMA PAKISTAN (PVT) LTD";
        },
                {
            firstentry = 3;
            secondentry = "ICI PAKISTAN LTD";
        },
                {
            firstentry = 21;
            secondentry = "ADAMJEE PHARMACEUTICALS (PVT) LTD.";
        },
                {
            firstentry = 12;
            secondentry = "BROOKES PHARMACEUTICAL LABORATORIES (PAK.) LTD.";
        },
                {
            firstentry = 4;
            secondentry = "STIEFEL LABORATORIES PAKISTAN (PVT) LTD";
        },
                {
            firstentry = 1;
            secondentry = "GENIX PHARMA (PVT) LTD";
        },

    );
}
```

Comment: 1) Identify the language.  (There are tags for this.)  2) Give the COMPLETE error message.  3) Include the exception stack trace.  4) You're trying to index a dictionary using an integer value.

Comment: 5) Don't use "long chain polymer" statements -- break your last line of code into two separate statements so you can debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is not an array. Try this :

```
NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];     

NSArray *firstArry=[jsonArray objectForKey:@"GetAllEmployeesMethodResult"];
```